# Permutation Group Notation

Tags: abstract-algebra, notation

I have a question about notation:

> For a permutation $\sigma\in S_n$, define the following quantities:
>
> - $\text{ret}(\sigma)$ as the number of indexes $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $\sigma(i)\lt i$
> - $\text{fix}(\sigma)$ as the number of indexes $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $\sigma(i)=i$
> - $\text{exc}(\sigma)$ as the number of indexes $1\leq i\leq n$ such that $\sigma(i)\gt i$

What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A permutation $\sigma$ is a bijection from a finite set to itself.  Here, it looks like we should think of $S_n\ni\sigma:\{1,2,\ldots,n\}\to\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$.  Now the definitions are clearer: $\sigma$ maps numbers to numbers.  You want to count the number of elements that are sent to numbers *less* than themselves, the number that are sent *to themselves*, and the number that are sent to numbers *greater* than themselves.

For example, if $\sigma = (1)(234)(5)(67)$, then we have the following:
$$\sigma(1)=1,\ \sigma(2)=3,\ \sigma(3)=4,\ \sigma(4)=2,\ \sigma(5)=5,\ \sigma(6)=7,\ \sigma(7)=6.$$
The numbers sent to themselves are $1,5$, the number sent to numbers less than themselves are $4,7$, an the number sent to numbers greater than themselves are $2,3,6$.  Thus $\operatorname{ret}(\sigma)=2$, $\operatorname{fix}(\sigma)=2$, and $\operatorname{exc}(\sigma) = 3$.